# insertSubview: AtIndex: does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, subview

I went through the material regarding this issue but still can't figure it out completely.
The main issue is that i am using this method but the view does not show...
The app is built out of two view - the main one (i added it as a subview to the main nib) - 
Has of a text field where i write some text. 
Has a button that when pressed, the action method loads a second view that has a label with some text in it.
the source code of the first viewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TxtRunnerViewController;

@interface Itai_s_text_app_take_2ViewController : UIViewController {
 int sliderSpeed;
 IBOutlet UITextField  *textInput;
 TxtRunnerViewController *trvc;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textInput;
@property (retain, nonatomic) TxtRunnerViewController *trvc;

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender;//speed of text show changed

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;//dor 'DONE' on keyboard
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;//for handling tapping on background

- (IBAction)textEmButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

the .m of the first ViewController:
    #import "Itai_s_text_app_take_2ViewController.h"
    #import "TxtRunnerViewController.h"

```
@implementation Itai_s_text_app_take_2ViewController
@synthesize textInput;
@synthesize trvc;


- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender
{
 UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
 sliderSpeed =  (int)(slider.value + 0.5f);//setting the speed determinned by the usr in slider
 NSLog(@"Slider value is %@", sliderSpeed);
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
 NSLog(@"our text input  is %@", textInput.text);
}

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
{
 [textInput resignFirstResponder]; 
}

- (IBAction)textEmButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
 NSLog(@"button pressed");
 if ([textInput.text length]==0) 
 {
  NSString *msg = nil;
  msg = @"Write text to transmit";
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Forgot something?"
              message:msg
                delegate:self
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" 
             otherButtonTitles:nil];

  [alert show]; 
  [alert release]; 
  [msg release];
 }
 else { //init 
  NSLog(@"HI!");
  if (self.trvc == nil)
  {
   NSLog(@"if accepted");
   TxtRunnerViewController *tr = [[TxtRunnerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TxtRunner"
                       bundle:nil];
   self.trvc = tr;
   [tr release];
  }
  [self.view removeFromSuperview];
  [self.view insertSubview:trvc.view atIndex:0];
  NSLog(@"InsertAtIndex was operated...!");
  //[self.view addSubview:tvc.view];
 }

}
/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

 // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
 if(self.trvc.view.superview == nil)
  self.trvc = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
 // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
 [trvc release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The second View is simply empty (has a label added to it in it's nib file):
    #import

```
@interface TxtRunnerViewController : UIViewController {

}

@end
```

It's .m file is the default one, added no code to it.
When i press the button in the first view - it's view disappears but the second view does not appear instead, only a blank white view appears, nothing on it.

Doe

Comment: please format your code as code sample "{}" above input or <pre><code> or Ctrl+K

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, the code:

Comment: How do i write the code so that the #import appears and the code is indented, and lines are ended (new-lines recognized)?

Comment: as I wrote above, use the "{}" button OR select the text and press Ctrl+K (on Mac cmd+K)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you push the TxtRunnerViewController it will completely hide the first one, but it still exist in background. (without removeFromSuperview)

```
TxtRunnerViewController *vw = [[TxtRunnerViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TxtRunner" bundle:nil];
[self.view pushViewController:vw.view animated:NO];
[vw release];
```

To remove the first view it's a bit more difficult. You would need to implement a delegate in RootViewController which will be fired after clicking the done Button of the first view. Then in your RootViewController some code is executed which displays the second view and removes the first view.

For a delegate sample open the Utility Application Sample when creating a new project and figure out how it works or search some examples online.

Answer (score 0):

The line: 
[self.view removeFromSuperview];

Removes the view from its super

then the call

```
[self.view insertSubview:trvc.view atIndex:0];
```

Adds trvc to it - but that view has been removed and not visible anymore.

You need to add trvc to the superview.

Comment: I'm a bit confused jamihash - how do i do that exactly? i thought that using insertAtIndex does just that.

Comment: Tried [super.view insertSubview...] - got a blank iphone screen as well.

Comment: remove the line [self.view removeFromSuperview]; and it should work. If you need to remove your self view you have to insert your trvc-view onto an other view instead of self, but for now remove the [self.view removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Yes, i did that and it worked, now i see both elements from the self. view and the ones from the trvc view's nib... i really am missing something here...

Comment: Really sorry for asking further but i believe my question touches a design issue as well:

Comment: All i am doing is making an app with 2 screens - the one you see in after load of the app, the "Itai_s_text_app_take_2ViewController", simply has a text field and a button. the button will fire up the load of the second view which will display a label on the screen.

Comment: So, all i did was the implementation above. thanks to IPortable and jamihash i managed to load the 2nd view as well, but i still see the elements of the first view - it's like both view are now displayed. How am i supposed to handle such a specfic and common operation of simply loading one view and then switching to another after the first view's button is pressed? What did i do wrong in my code above?